# Anonymous Authentication in IIS to WCF service routes in an otherwise windows authenicated website

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, routes, wcf-security

I have an ASP.NET Web Site that requires Windows authentication with the exception of a WCF service that is hosted in the application and requires anonymous authentication:

(let's say: `FooService.svc`)

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements( RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed )]
[ServiceBehavior( InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public partial class FooService
{
    [WebGet( UriTemplate = "foo", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
    public string GetFoo()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

and I have registered my routes in `Global.asax`:

```
routes.Add( new ServiceRoute( "MyService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof( FooService ) ) );
```

My problem is making this service and all of its routes allow anonymous authentication (as an exception to the rest of the Windows Authenitcated site).

I have been able to achieve this only by creating a folder that matches the name of the route (`http://MyHost/MyWebsite/`*MyService*`/`) leave it empty, and enable anonymous authentication to the directory in IIS.

Is there a better way of allowing anonymous authentication to my service routes in IIS that does not involve creating a folder only to exist as a place holder for IIS configuration?

**Additional Note:** I have found that after configuring the empty folder in IIS to allow anonymous access, I can delete the physical folder and the anonymous authentication for the service route is still honored.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any empty folders on your website. You can just add application to your website in IIS and set anonymous authentication on this application. Other approach is to use windows authentication. What is the reason your service require anonymous authentication?

Comment: I am looking to have only one application in IIS. The application requires Windows Authentication with the exception of the service. The service requires Anonymous Authentication because it needs to be accessed by clients that do not support Windows Authentication.

Comment: What is the problem with having multiple applications within 1 website?